# Sitecore cannot find placeholders for JSS

Tags: jss

There is a problem. Sitecore site with JSS frontend. In experience editor everything is fine, but in normal mode pop up mistake: Placeholder 'header' was not found in the current rendering data, Placeholder 'main' was not found in the current rendering data. What can be a problem ? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Problem was in not full published jss files from master database to web, after full republishing everything became fine.